# SimpleDateFormat gives a wrong date when input a wrong format date string

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

code is

```
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        Date date = format.parse("2024-03-01 09:20:46");
```

the `date`'s value is `Sun Dec 03 00:01:09 CST 2023` without any Exception.

I read some comment in jdk, it might show that '-' will treat to minus , is it real?
And how to understand the read think in the method   SimpleDateFormat.parse

Comment: Stop using `SimpleDateFormat`: it is a long-outdated API. Use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`, available since Java 8.

Comment: And if you *must* use SimpleDateFormat, have you tried using `setLenient(false)`?

Comment: @JonSkeet it works after using `setLenient(false)`! And I also want to know why the '-' is treated as subtraction and went back some time range : )

Comment: I'm not sure whether by "works" you mean "still parses without error" or "fails as expected". As to the "why" question - it's not clear to me that it really *is* being treated as subtraction, but I don't think it's really worth going into the details of *exactly* how the old date/time APIs are awful. They're just awful - move off them.

Comment: Out of interest, why did you choose that particular datetime format *and then* provide a string to parse *in an entirely different format*?

Comment: @g00se I would assume that string and format was provided as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  for our convenience. After having experienced this situation in more complicated real code, the author now wishes to explore the behavior they encountered.

Comment: *And I also want to know why the '-' is treated as subtraction and went back some time range : )* You would have to ask the designers if you can find them. Or just forget about `SimpleDateFormat`. It has been observed before that `SimpleDateFormat` accepts negative numbers as input and extrapolates into the past. Just one of very many confusing ways it behaves. (That it skips the space in the string an apparently interprets `09` as seconds is new to me.)

Comment: If you are really curious (it’s nothing you need to understand), going backwards in time is not because of any minus and/or negative number in your case. The interpretation is year 2024, month -0, same as 0, so the month before month 1 = January, so December the year before. Day 3, hour -0 = 0, minute 1 and as I said, second 09.

Comment: As everyone here seems to say, use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Declare `private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");`. Then try `LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2024-03-01 09:20:46", PARSER);`. It gives your expected exception: `DateTimeParseException: Text '2024-03-01 09:20:46' could not be parsed at index 4`. Enjoy the precise and helpful exception message.

Comment: @JonSkeet Setting the `SimpleDateFormat` non-lenient is no real solution. It catches the incorrect format in this particular case but will miss other examples of mismatch between format pattern and parsed string. Getting `SimpleDateFormat` to behave reasonably at best requires much more. As more users already said: don’t bother.

Answer (score 2):

As the Comments explain:

- If you want strict parsing, without tolerating problematic inputs, **specify strict parsing**.
- You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that are now legacy. Those classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. **Use only *java.time* classes.**

### [`ResolverStyle.STRICT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT)

In *java.time*, specify parsing strictness on a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class by calling [`withResolverStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withResolverStyle(java.time.format.ResolverStyle)), and passing a [`ResolverStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html) enum object: `LENIENT`, `SMART` , [`STRICT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT).

### ISO 8601

By the way, your example input string nearly complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format used by default in *java.time* for parsing/generating text. Merely replace the SPACE character in the middle with a `T`.

### `java.time.LocalDateTime`

Then you can parse as a `LocalDateTime`. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2024-03-01 09:20:46".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Be aware that a `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. A `LocalDateTime` object is inherently ambiguous in that it represents only a date with time-of-day while lacking the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Comment: Correct! The use of error-prone legacy API must be avoided. This answer can be improved by adding a section and code about the exception, like [Annonymous has already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78205257/simpledateformat-gives-a-wrong-date-when-input-a-wrong-format-date-string/78207932#comment137878826_78205257).

Answer (score -1):

use DateTimeFormatter

or

you can do this

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse("2024-03-01 09:20:46");
```

Comment: `java.util` datetimes should be avoided at all costs

Comment: @g00se The costs are small or zero. Of course, if you learned Java more than 10 years ago and didn’t stay up to date, you have something to learn. After that you will be getting the benefits quickly.